# Maven 3.0.3 uses old JUnit Plugin which doesn't have org.junit.* package

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm using Hudson and trying to build a maven project from subversion repository. 
Problem is, that Maven downloads an old junit version, I guess, because I found this:

> Downloading: ..repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.pom
>   Downloaded: ..repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.pom (998 B at 2.0 KB/sec)

Later it complains that package org.junit.* doesn't exist.

### When I instead let Hudson built a local copy of this project (not subversion managed), it starts the junit test:

### T E S T S

Running JUnitTest
...

My pom.xml looks like this:

http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2227

(I also tried 
    junit
    4.8.2
 without the square brackets, which didn't help anything.
)

How do I get the JUnit Tests to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though junit `dependency` with `4.8.2` version is specified in the pom, it is between `<dependencyManagement>` tag.  As such that version will not be used, unless the dependendency is **explicitly** defined in the build.

You could fix the problem in two ways.

Remove the outer `<dependencyManagement>` tag - just retain the contents.

Define the following in addition to what is present in the pom file between `<dependencyManagement>` and `<build>` tags.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

[Pom reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html)